# Can "inexact" heat and work differentials be thought of as one-forms in a manifold whose path-dependency "somehow" always cancels out when added?

Tags: thermodynamics, general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, differential-equations

Thermodynamic Law 1 is dU = dQ - dW

dQ and dW both have the property of being path dependant (i.e. there is no such thing as a Barrow Evaluation Formula for integrating dQ), while we (for equilibrium states in basic thermo) ask for U to be well defined independently of the history.

In General Relativity there is a notion of transporting tangent vectors from P1 to P2 in 2 different ways and giving rise to two different vectors, and the same applies for one-forms if one introduces the metric (1,1) tensor.

How does the "two independent path dependent vectors add up one path independent one" issue is explained in GR?

NOTE: Actually dQ and dW are not independent since the 2nd Law poses some constraints, but I don't want to adress this issue unless the actual question needs it!